# Convert Array to Google Lat/Lng Array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the array

```
[[[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]],[[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]]]
```

What I would like to do is conver this into,

```
  var paths = [[
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.872886, -77.054720),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.872602, -77.058046),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.870080, -77.058604),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.868894, -77.055664),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.870598, -77.053346)
  ], [
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.871684, -77.056780),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.871867, -77.055449),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.870915, -77.054891),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.870113, -77.055836),
    new google.maps.LatLng(38.870581, -77.057037)
  ]];
```

Where each

```
[[11.11,11.11],[22.22,22.22],[33.33,33.33]]
```

of my array is a new array Google LatLng Markers.

I have tried using map function on the array like this:

```
  point.map(new google.maps.LatLng(point))
```

But get a NaN error. Do I need to break everypoint out or can I do this more fluidly with a call such as map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested loops?

```
var input = [
    [
        [11.11, 11.11],
        [22.22, 22.22],
        [33.33, 33.33]
    ],
    [
        [11.11, 11.11],
        [22.22, 22.22],
        [33.33, 33.33]
    ]
];
var paths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var path = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
        path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(input[i][j][0], input[i][j][1]));
    }
    paths.push(path);
}
console.dir(paths);​
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GMMCy/1/)